# Flutter and Getx State Management - List View Changes

Tags: flutter, dart, get, flutter-getx

Creating one Shopping App using flutter with Getx State Management. I don't know how to create a controller for each element in the list. So that, any changes in the particular element in the list it will reload only that element not the entire list reload.

[image]

If I Clicked "New Order" Container, other Container("Order Confirmed", "Completed") also rebuilds (entire list view rebuilds).

My Model :

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class TabModel {
  late String tabName;
  RxBool isSelected = false.obs;

  TabModel(this.tabName);
}
```

My Controller :

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:super_mart_merchant/view/orders/view_models/tab_model.dart';
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class TabViewController extends GetxController{
  RxList<TabModel> tabModels = <TabModel>[].obs;
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    loadVal('New Order',true);
    loadVal('Order Confirmed',false);
    loadVal('Order Declined',false);
    loadVal('Completed',false);
  }

  void loadVal(String name,bool isSelected){
    TabModel tabModel = TabModel(name);
    tabModel.isSelected.value = isSelected;
    tabModels.add(tabModel);
  }

  void onClick(int pos){
    TabModel tabModel =   tabModels[pos];
    if(!tabModel.isSelected.value){
      TabModel? previousTabModel =  tabModels.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element.isSelected.value);
      if(previousTabModel != null){
        previousTabModel.isSelected.value = false;
      }
      tabModel.isSelected.value = true;

    }

  }
}
```

Binding:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:super_mart_merchant/view/orders/controllers/tab_controller.dart';

class TabControllerBinding implements Bindings{
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut<TabViewController>(() => TabViewController());

  }
}
```

View :

```
class TabView extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetX<TabViewController>(
      builder: (TabViewController tabController) {
        print('Object called : ${tabController.toString()}');
        return Container(
          height: 55,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, int index) {
              if (tabController.tabModels[index].isSelected.value) {
                return SelectedOrderStatusComponents(
                    tabController.tabModels[index],
                    index);
              }
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  tabController.onClick(index);
                },
                child: UnSelectedOrderStatusComponents(
                    tabController.tabModels[index],
                    index),
              );
            },
            itemCount: tabController.tabModels.length,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In Provider we have options for this. I don't how to do that in Getx. Great Thanks!!!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my first time answering here so I hope it is up to the standard, also not too late for your problems.
For your first problem: wanting to keep each tab from rebuilding after navigate in Tabs. You could convert the Tab widget to Stateful widget and add `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` to prevent it from rebuilding after navigating. Something like this:

```
class TabView extends StatefulWidget {
  TabView ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TabViewState createState() => _TabViewState();
}

class _TabViewState extends State<TabView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Container();
  }
  
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

For your second problem, to just reload the item and not the whole list, you can wrap each item in a `Obx` or `GetBuilder` and give it a tag base on the index or id of each item, but I don't recommend doing this since GetX is quite fast in rebuilding, it only rebuild where changed and having too many GetBuilder in one page can affect performance.

```
return GestureDetector(
     onTap: (){
          tabController.onClick(index);
     },
     child: GetBuilder<TabViewController>(
          id: "item" + tabController.tabModels[index].id,
          builder: (controller) {
              return UnSelectedOrderStatusComponents(
                   tabController.tabModels[index],
                   index);
          }
     )
);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your valuable answer. Based on your second answer I have solved my problem. Wrapping with GetX each item instead of the whole list.

Comment: AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin not available in Get WIdget right?